# JSF h:SelectOneMenu does not convert to Number

Tags: jsf

I am using Sun JSF-RI 1.2 and having grief with h:SelectOneMenu.
The value is bound to a backing bean field of type Object.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.currentNumber}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{bean.numberList}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The SelectItems are created as follows:

```
SelectItem option = new SelectItem(new Double(3),"3");
```

I expect my backing bean to be injected with an object of type Double but instead
all I get is a String "3"

I believe JSF should convert it correctly, other wise what is the point in having a

```
SelectItem(Object val,String label)
```

Constructor, if all its good for is strings

Please help !!!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type from `Object` to `Double` or add `converter="javax.faces.Double"` to the `<h:selectOneMenu>`.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using a converter since I need the flexibility of Object. Still strange since there is a very clear mapping to the right  type of object when constructing the selectItem

Comment: You're welcome. No, it is not strange. HTML is basically one large `String` and request parameters arrive as `String`. You have to explicitly specify the Java type by using the right property type and/or a converter. The selectitem types are irrelevant, they end up as `String` in HTML anyway.